# What is the OData Feeds

Tags: wcf-data-services

I saw "feeds" this word many times in the WCF data service tutorial. But I really don't know what "feeds" means. Can anybody help me ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feed is the ATOM concept - it means collection of entities in WCF Data services.

Comment: Hi . Can I says the OData is belong to ATOM specification or OData is in the part of ATOM specification?